# how to set the text containings emoji char to textView

Tags: android, textview, emoji

when getting some text from server and put in textView, found some char cannot display (on os M). It turns out there are some emoji char in the text.

something similar to do like:

```
theTextGotFromServer = "some text, then emoji code: \uD83D\uDE46\uD83C\uDFFE\uD83E\uDD16 some more text";
mTextView.setText(fromCardInfo);
```

But on OS 7, all the emoji char are displayed correctly with the emojis.